# Can stack overflows be mitigated by having arrays grow upward instead of down into the return address / stack frame?

Tags: stack, buffer

Can stack overﬂows be mitigated by having arrays grow upward instead of 
down into the return address / stack frame?

Comment: is this your homework or something? Can you be more specific or show some codes of what have you tried?

Comment: Did you rather mean "buffer overflow-based exploits"?

Answer (score 1):

> Can stack overﬂows be mitigated by having arrays grow upward instead of down

Quite simply: No. Don't you think that this would be standard, if that were the case?

You seem to be conflating two different behaviors. I don't see what stack overflows have to do with arrays. In the case of infinite recursion: memory is not infinite, so at *some* point the code will need memory (for another stack frame) which is simply not available.